# Using -P with mvn install command in a script .

Tags: linux, maven

I have this Linux script inside our server . This script is used for building the Application .

```
cvs checkout MacMoira
cd MacMoira
mvn clean 
mvn install -P MacMoira
exit 0
```

I did not understand this line "mvn install -P MacMoira" . 
Could anybody please tell me what is the use of using -P with mvn install .

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-P` specifies a profile in Maven with specific settings (in this case the profile `MacMoira`)

See: [Introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you run `mvn --help` it will return this information:

```
[...]
-P,--activate-profiles <arg>           Comma-delimited list of profiles
                                        to activate
[...]
```

within the maven's pom.xml there are `<profiles>` specified, these you can activate using the `-P` flag